# Using format() in pathlib.Path

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm trying to set a variable to point to a file on the desktop that's generated and named containing today's date. But I'm getting the following error:

```
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

The file is to be attached to an Outlook email. I know pathlib requires an absolute path to be stated, but what if I'd like to use format() to make it point to a file whose name changes daily when it's generated?

This is an automation task, so it would be ideal if I could make the date reflect today's date without having to make changes to the code. Thanks in advance!

```
import win32com.client as client
import pathlib
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()
image_path = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/username/Desktop/Folder {}/Filename {}.png'.format(x.strftime("%b %d")))
```

Comment: what's the error here? it works well for me

Comment: Well, and did you encounter any problem when trying to do that? I fail to see a question in your post...

Comment: Edited to add error message.

Comment: It works perfectly for me as well. Please provide a minimal code example that reproduces the problem, this one doesn't.

Comment: I've modified the code to be closer to what I was trying to do now (simplified it in the original as I thought it would make the problem clearer). The path I set used the {} in two parts of the code. I tried replacing just one of the braces with today's date in both positions and it worked. It seems format() only applies to one pair of braces but not two pairs, even if I'd like the date to apply twice in the path?

Comment: You have 2 slots to fill in your string, so you need to provide 2 replacements in `format`, but you provide only one.

Comment: Great thanks that seems to have been the problem. I repeated ```x.strftime("% b %d")``` again separated by a comma and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use empty `{}` as placeholders, it is expected that each has to be replaced by a different value, so you'll need to provide as many replacements in `format`.

If you want to use the same value twice, you can number them so that both use the argument to `format` with index 0:

```
import pathlib
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()
image_path = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/username/Desktop/Folder {0}/Filename {0}.png'.format(x.strftime("%b %d")))

print(image_path)
# C:/Users/username/Desktop/Folder Aug 08/Filename Aug 08.png
```